# Mapping with inheritance does not work due to downcast error

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to cast the an object of type `NamespaceB.SearchResult` to `NamespaceA.SearchResult` (exactly the same structure, just different namespace) with the below configurations and resulsts:

#### Source/destination types

Just make sure you duplicate `AutoMapper_Test.NamespaceA` and rename it to `AutoMapper_Test.NamespaceB`.

```
namespace AutoMapper_Test.NamespaceA
{
    //Types
    class SearchResult
    {
        public SearchItem[] SearchItems { get; set; }
    }

    class SearchItem
    {
        public BaseProfile Profile { get; set; }

        public DerivedProfile[] SubProfiles { get; set; }
    }

    //Property Types
    class BaseProfile
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }

    class DerivedProfile : BaseProfile 
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}

public static SearchResult CreateData()
    {
        var profile = new NamespaceB.BaseProfile { Id = "5" };
        var derivedProfile = new List<NamespaceB.DerivedProfile>();
        derivedProfile.Add(new NamespaceB.DerivedProfile { Name = "Test", Id = "4" });

        var profile1 = new NamespaceB.BaseProfile { Id = "6" };
        var derivedProfile1 = new List<NamespaceB.DerivedProfile>();
        derivedProfile1.Add(new NamespaceB.DerivedProfile { Name = "Test", Id = "7" });

        var item = new NamespaceB.SearchItem
        { 
            Profile = profile,
            SubProfiles = derivedProfile.ToArray()
        };

        var item1 = new NamespaceB.SearchItem
        { 
            Profile = profile1,
            SubProfiles = derivedProfile1.ToArray()
        };

        var searchItems = new List<NamespaceB.SearchItem>();
        searchItems.Add(item);
        searchItems.Add(item1);

        return new NamespaceB.SearchResult { SearchItems = searchItems.ToArray() };
    }

    public static void ConfigureMappings()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
            cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = false;
            cfg.CreateMap<NamespaceA.SearchResult, NamespaceB.SearchResult>();
        });
    }

//Main
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ConfigureMappings();

    var searchResultBeta = CreateData(); //namespaceB
    var searchResult = Mapper.Map<NamespaceA.SearchResult>(searchResultBeta);
    System.Console.WriteLine(searchResult.SearchItems.Length);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

#### Mapping configuration

```
public static void ConfigureMappings()
{
    var mappings = new MapperConfigurationExpression();
    mappings.CreateMap<NamespaceA.SearchResult, NamespaceB.SearchResult>();
    Mapper.Initialize(mappings);
}
```

#### Automapper Version: 7.0.1

#### Exception details

```
Unhandled Exception: AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
SearchResult -> SearchResult
AutoMapper_Test.NamespaceB.SearchResult -> AutoMapper_Test.NamespaceA.SearchResult

Type Map configuration:
SearchResult -> SearchResult
AutoMapper_Test.NamespaceB.SearchResult -> AutoMapper_Test.NamespaceA.SearchResult

Property:
SearchItems ---> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
SearchItem -> SearchItem
AutoMapper_Test.NamespaceB.SearchItem -> AutoMapper_Test.NamespaceA.SearchItem

Type Map configuration:
SearchItem -> SearchItem
AutoMapper_Test.NamespaceB.SearchItem -> AutoMapper_Test.NamespaceA.SearchItem

Property:
SubProfiles ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'AutoMapper_Test.NamespaceA.BaseProfile' to type 'AutoMapper_Test.NamespaceA.DerivedProfile'.
   at lambda_method(Closure , SearchResult , SearchResult , ResolutionContext )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at lambda_method(Closure , SearchResult , SearchResult , ResolutionContext )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at lambda_method(Closure , SearchResult , SearchResult , ResolutionContext )
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object , ResolutionContext )
   at AutoMapper.Mapper.AutoMapper.IMapper.Map[TDestination](Object source) in C:\projects\automapper\src\AutoMapper\Mapper.cs:line 207
   at AutoMapper_Test.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Projects\AutoMapper Test\Program.cs:line 55
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. Where is `DerivedProfile` and `BaseProfile`? We need to be able to copy, paste, and compile your code so that we can see the same error as you.

Comment: Check now. For simplicity, I didn't duplicate the content of `AutoMapper_Test.NamespaceA` namespace.

Comment: It's an improvement, but you still have things like `List<DerivedProfile>()` in your code. Which namespace is that?

Comment: My mistake. The default namespace is `NamespaceB`. I've updated the code accordingly.

Comment: This is not a proper repro, but if I make it run, it complains about missing maps, which makes sense, because you're not creating the needed maps.